# Use null values to pad the ValueRange for values().update

Tags: google-sheets-api

Google Sheets API v4 is not passing `null` values as part of a `ValueRange`.

When a `ValueRange` is created with the following values:

> "Test A", "Test B", null, null, "Test E"

with the range:

> "A1:E1"

I get the following result:

```
   A       B       C       D       E
1  Test A  Test B  Test E
```

But the expected result is:

```
   A       B       C       D       E
1  Test A  Test B                  Test E
```

The API used is `spreadsheets().values().update(ID, range, ValueRange)`

One possible solution is setting `ValueInputOption` to "USER_ENTERED" if not done already, however the problem still persists.

Here is a SSCCE in Java:

```
public static void test(Sheets service, String id) {
    String range = "A1:E1";
    List<List<Object>> values = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("Test A", "Test B", null, null, "Test E"));
    ValueRange vRange = new ValueRange();
    vRange.setRange(range);
    vRange.setValues(values);
    try {
        System.out.println(service.spreadsheets().values().update(id, range, vRange)
                .setValueInputOption("USER_ENTERED").execute().toPrettyString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And the result:

```
{
  "spreadsheetId" : "[id]",
  "updatedCells" : 3,
  "updatedColumns" : 3,
  "updatedRange" : "Sheet1!A1:C1",
  "updatedRows" : 1
}
```

What changes need to be made to get `null` recognized, so that E will end up in the E column instead of the `null` values being glanced over?

Comment: Please post your sample code, the data in the spreadsheet, and the output you get.  The Sheets API should trim trailing empty values, but should not be excluded empty values between other non-empty ones.

Comment: Try **`null`** and use **`valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED`**, this is following the document "[Write selectively to a range](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/writing#write_selectively_to_a_range)". Hope this helps.

Comment: using valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED solved the problem. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

I ran through a similar problem.

You can use `Data.NULL_STRING` (from `com.google.api.client.util`) instead of a native java `null`.

Fixed it for me